# Controller Name in filter Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I am creating a Laravel before filter that will get the controller name and method along with the route and input requests and will create a log of it. There will also be a filter for after which will also log all the detals of response in log file.

This is what i have done so far

```
Route::when('*', 'log', array('post' , 'get' , 'put' ,'delete'));


Route::filter('log', function($route) {

var_dump($route);
});
```

I have got the route but its a huge file and i cant get the contrller and method out of it..

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at what **$route->getAction()** returns. It's an array that describes what controller should be executed when given route is executed.

In order to get the controller name and method name you can do:

```
list($controller, $method) = explode('@', $route->getActionName());
```